# WPF - свои имена столбцов в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

Не могу понять каким образом установить свои наименования заголовкам столбцов?
Во View есть DataGrid, который должен выводить инфу:

```
<DataGrid FontSize="8"  
                              Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding CaloriesGrid}"
                              >

                    </DataGrid>
```

Объект Grid, который должен выводиться в DataGrid:

```
public class Grid
        {
            [DisplayName("Дни недели")]
            public string Day { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Не изменяя вес")]
            public double? CalcCalories { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Потеря веса")]
            public double? CalcCaloriesWeightLoss { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Быстрая потеря веса")]
            public double? CalcCaloriesWeightLossFast { get; set; }                      
        }
```

Указал атрибут DisplayName - не работает.

Пробовал во View привязать через DataGrid.Column - не получается. Точнее получается, но плюсом выводятся те же наименования столбцов, указанные в классе Grid:

```
<DataGrid FontSize="8"  
                              Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding GridCalories}"
                              >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Day}" Width="*" Header="Дни недели" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CalcCalories}" Width="*" Header="Не изменяя вес" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CalcCaloriesWeightLoss}" Width="*" Header="Потеря веса" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CalcCaloriesWeightLossFast}" Width="*" Header="Быстрая потеря веса" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: DataGrid.Columns - правильный путь. Попробуйте AutoGenerateColumns ="False" в определении DataGrid.

Comment: Господи, дай Бог тебе здоровья. Спасибо!